# Download pdf file with Vue js in mevn stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have the following method in my node backend that generates the pdf and saves in the server directory `data/invoices/`.

```js
exports.generateInvoice = async(req, res, next) => {
    const orderId = req.params.orderId;
    try {
        const order = await  Order.findById(orderId);
        const data = await order.populate("user.userId").execPopulate();
        if (!order){
            const error = new Error("Order not found");
            error.statusCode = 404;
            throw  error;
        }
        if (data.user.userId._id.toString() !== req.userId.toString()) {
            return next(new Error("Unauthorized"));
        }

        const invoiceName = "invoice-" + orderId + ".pdf";
        const invoicePath = path.join("data", "invoices", invoiceName);

        let doc = new PDFDocument({ size: "A4", margin: 50 });
        generateHeader(doc);
        generateCustomerInformation(doc, data);
        generateInvoiceTable(doc, data);
        generateFooter(doc);

        doc.end();
        doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(invoicePath));
        res.status(200).json({path: 'http://localhost:8080/'+invoicePath});

    }catch (e){
        if (!e.statusCode) {
            e.statusCode = 500;
            next(e);
        }
    }
}
```

```
generateHeader(doc);
generateCustomerInformation(doc, data);
generateInvoiceTable(doc, data);
generateFooter(doc);
```

are just helper methods that I've created.

And this is my frontend vue method that triggers the above method to generate the invoice pdf.

```js
  methods: {
    async getInvoice(orderId){
      console.log("click");
      const res = await this.$axios.get('product/get-invoice/'+ orderId, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.userData.userToken
        }
      });

      console.log(res);
    }
  },
```

How can I download the recently created pdf ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This somehow does the job but still looking
for efficient way.

In server / app.js. Added static path to invoice directory

```
app.use("/invoice", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "data/invoices")));
```

Pass file name to the frontend.

```
exports.generateInvoice = async(req, res, next) => {
  ...........
  res.json({
    path: invoiceName
  });
}
```

In Order.vue

```
async getInvoice(orderId) {
  console.log("click");
  const res = await this.$axios.get('product/get-invoice/' + orderId, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.userData.userToken
    }
  });
  window.open('http://localhost:8080/invoice/' + res.data.path, '_blank');
}
```